# How can I characterize this class of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

**My problem:**

Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{E},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and that $X$ is defined in $\Omega$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$.

We say that a random variable $Y$ is $X$-measurable if $Y : (\Omega,\sigma(X)) \to (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is measurable where $\sigma(X)= \{ X^{-1}(A): A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$.

How can we prove that if $Z$ is a bounded real-valued random variable $\sigma(X)$-measurable then $Z=g(X)$ where $g$ is a bounded measurable function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

**My attempt:**

I am able to prove it if I do not assume $Z$ is bounded but of course I do not get $g$ is bounded.

Comment: Hint: First prove for simple functions, then for linear combinations of simple functions, and so on.

Comment: If you can prove it without the boundedness assumption, you've also proved it with the boundedness assumption, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose first that $Z=\sum_{i<n} \alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i}$ is simple and $\sigma(X)$-measurable, with $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$. Note that $A_i=\{Z=\alpha_i\}\in \sigma(X)$, thus $A_i=X^{-1}(B_i)$ for some Borel set $B_i\subset\mathbb{R}$. Thus,
\begin{equation}
Z=\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i}=\sum_{i<n} \alpha_i \mathbf{1}_{B_i}(X)=\underbrace{\left(\sum_{i<n}\alpha_i\mathbf{1}_{B_i}\right)}_{g}(X).
\end{equation}
Since $g$ is Borel, every simple function has the property in question.

Fix now $Z\ge 0$ which is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and bounded (say by $M$). Pick an increasing sequence of simple random variables $Z_n\nearrow Z$, where each $Z_n$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable. By the previous paragraph, $Z_n=g_n(X)$ for some Borel function $g_n$. Define
\begin{equation*}
g^*(x):=\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x) & \text{ if  }\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(x) \text{ exists,} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
As the set $\{x: \lim_n g_n(x) \text{ exists}\}$ is Borel, $g^*$ is Borel measurable.
Now note that
\begin{equation}
X=\lim_n X_n =\lim_n g_n(Z)=g(Z),
\end{equation}
Let
\begin{equation*}
g(x):=\begin{cases}
g^*(x) & \text{ if  }|g(x)|\le M\\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then $g(Z)=g^*(Z)$ and $g$ is Borel and bounded, which establishes the claim for non-negative random variables.

Given an arbitrary $\sigma(X)$-measurable $Z$, write $Z=Z^+-Z^-$, pick $g,h$ Borel such that $g(X)=Z^+$ and $h(X)=Z^-$, so that
\begin{equation}
Z=g(X)-h(X)=(g-h)(X)
\end{equation}
and we are done, as $g-h$ is Borel and bounded.